# Como modelar parcelas quando não se sabe quantas são?

Tags: banco-de-dados, classes, modelagem

Normalmente, quando se trata de pagamentos parcelados, se vem a ideia de 12 prestações.

Então você logo cria uma tabela com 12 campos, um para cada parcela.

Mas estou diante da situação de que o cliente é consumidor de prestação de serviços continuada: cliente de internet via rádio.

Ou seja, não existe parcela 1 de x.

Neste caso, como ficaria a lógica de criação das classes e tabelas?

Comment: você não cria 12 colunas. Cria outra tabela, com id, data, e valor da parcela etc. Essa informação deve ficar em linhas e não colunas. Ja imaginou como checar as parcelas não pagas em janeiro? 11 comparações?

Comment: "Então você logo cria uma tabela com 12 campos, um para cada parcela". Na verdade nunca tinha visto ninguém fazer isso hehehe O jeito mais simples é como disse o @rray.

Comment: @Caffé se for no excel isso aí é até 'aceitavel' :P

Comment: @rray pois olhe... acho que até no excel eu faria uma planilha à parte para as parcelas, com lookup para o contrato :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É muito simples, o erro já começa na ideia que existem prestações fixas. O cliente não tem uma dívida com 12 prestações, ele tem 12 dívidas.

Você pode ter um contrato que originou estas dívidas e talvez queira vincular a isto. Se for o caso, é só fazer a vinculação através de um campo, assim como vai vincular a dívida com o cliente. Se a vinculação com um contrato for obrigatória, nem precisa vincular com o cliente, porque o contrato já terá este vínculo.

Note que estou especulando aqui, você não fala em contrato ou outros detalhes, fica mais difícil ajudar sem entender todo o problema. Na verdade estes problemas em geral acontecem porque falta a conceituação certa, e isto não podemos ajudar muito sem uma longa conversa, o que não é o objetivo do site.

Mas se tiver que gerenciar contratos tem muita coisa envolvida aí.

Em qualquer situação você deve usar uma tabela com cada fatura/boleto/duplicata/nota promissória/previsão/etc. Cada documento deve ter uma entrada nesta tabela. Assim você pode ter quantos quiser, pode ter 1, 12 ou milhares.

Isto é especialmente necessário quando a quantidade é indeterminada. Cada título (nome genérico dado ao que está sendo cobrado) vai sendo inserido no sistema aos poucos. Provavelmente por um gerador. Você não pode lançar 3, 12, ou 1000 títulos para o cliente, a não ser que exista um contrato dizendo que tenha essa quantidade. Em contratos por tempo indeterminado cada título é gerado mês a mês enquanto o contrato não é encerrado.

O valor pode variar de um mês para o outro, seja por correção, mudança de pacote, serviços acessórios, descontos por falhas, promoções, ajustes de cobranças passadas, etc. Se não sabe o valor, não pode lançar automático, principalmente com muita antecipação. Até dá para automatizar o lançamento mensal.

Tem que haver um controle sobre o que será gerado se quiser automatizar esta parte, o que é uma parte do controle de contratos que eu disse antes. A automatização pode lançar um título novo cada mês com valor base. Este valor pode ser ajustado pelo gerenciamento de contratos. Ele pode considerar lançamentos manuais que são feitos mês a mês ou que estejam acessoriamente cadastrados no contrato ou adendo de contrato.

Mas pode ser feito manualmente com algum controle se foi gerado título do mês para todos os clientes. É uma forma mais simples e que dá menos trabalho para o programador e mais para o usuário.

Tem várias maneiras de implementar isto e poderemos ajudar quando tiver com mais detalhes.

Enfim, a maioria dos sistemas são mais complicados do que parecem e não é possível passar toda informação em uma única resposta em um site qualquer.

Aprenda sobre [normalização](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Falou tudo o que eu ia dizer e mais um pouco +1

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que o mais adequado seja criar uma tabela com parcelas já pagas, isso depende um pouco de como está o seu sistema.

Parcelas pagas devem ter os campos, id_parcela, data_pagamento, valor, pode ter o id do contranto (caso exista uma valor acordado que será cobrado por 12 meses, depois disso é feito um novo contrato com um novo valor) ou id do cliente.

Comment: Pensei nisso também. Mas vamos ver se os pensamentos batem: Ao invés de eu lançar as 'n' prestações, pois não temos o valor de 'n' pois o contrato é indeterminado, basta guardar no banco os campos, idCliente, mes_ano_parcela, dataPgtoParcela, quando o cliente vier pagar. Obs.: O pagamento não é por boleto, e sim lançamento direto com a atendente no próprio escritório!